# Convert UTM to latlon rasterBrick R

Tags: r, raster, netcdf

```
library(raster)
library(ncdf)
library(rgdal)
```

I am facing some issues converting `UTM` to `latlon` in a rasterBrick object. My code is below:

Example file can be found here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/yv4opmrx1v4whpt/2013_000_CaPA_continental_v2.3-analyse_final_10km_6h_APCP.nc.7z?dl=0

```
rasnc<- brick('file.nc', varname = "APCP_surface")

rasnc
#class       : RasterBrick 
#dimensions  : 824, 935, 770440, 1460  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
#resolution  : 10000, 10000  (x, y)
#extent      : -5000, 9345000, -5000, 8235000  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 

wgs84.p4s <- "+proj=longlat +datum=NAD83 +ellps=GRS80 +no_defs"
# reprojecting
rx <- projectRaster(from=rasnc, crs=wgs84.p4s,method="ngb")
```

The above does not convert from `UTM` to `latlon`. I even tried to write the file to GeoTIFF and then re-project but it still did not work.

```
writeRaster(rasnc, file="myfil.tif", format="GTiff", overwrite=TRUE)
```

Basically I am trying to:

- read a `netCDF` file.nc using `brick`
- convert the UTM coordinates to latlon
- crop the RasterBrick object to `ext <- extent(-141.01807,-52.61941,41.68144.0,83.13550)`
- display any of the layers using `levelplot` function.

The time series is 6-hourly from Jan-01-2013 to dec-01-2013

It is true my use of the older raster package version was the source of the problem as suggested by @RobertH. `rasnc` has no `coord.ref`. From the webpage `(http://weather.gc.ca/grib/grib2_RDPA_ps10km_e.html)` of the data modellers, it is stated  a `polar-stereographic (PS) grid` covering North America and adjacent waters with a 10 km resolution at 60 degrees north is used. How can I get the right `PS` for `rasnc` after which I will apply `projectRaster` to `rasnc` to get `latlon` coordinates

Comment: Please provide more information. Why do you say it "fails to convert"? How do you know that? And what is `crs(rasnc)`?

Comment: @RobertH I added the output metadata for `rasnc`; `rx <- projectRaster(from=rasnc, crs=wgs84.p4s,method="ngb")` still gives me UTM coordinates and does not return the original resolution of `rasnc`. Thus I am unable to plot any layer using `levelplot` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `rasnc` reports that it has a lon/lat coordinate reference system (`#coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84`); which looks incorrect. If you know what it should be, (you say UTM, but what is the zone?), assign it:

```
  crs(rasnc) <- '+proj=utm +zone=??? +datum=WGS84'
```

and then things should work.
The question is, how did this go wrong?

I get:

```
library(raster)
r <- brick("2013_000_CaPA_continental_v2.3-analyse_final_10km_6h_APCP.nc")
#Loading required namespace: ncdf4
#r
#class       : RasterBrick 
#dimensions  : 824, 935, 770440, 1460  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
#resolution  : 10000, 10000  (x, y)
#extent      : -5000, 9345000, -5000, 8235000  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : NA
```

which is correct as this file does not provide coordinate reference system information.

First update your version of raster (you are using ncdf instead of ncdf4, so we can see it is old); and do not leave out code (if you set the coord. ref. system yourself)

Comment: It is true my use of the older raster package version was the source of the problem. `rasnc` has no `coord.ref`. From the webpage `(http://weather.gc.ca/grib/grib2_RDPA_ps10km_e.html)` of the data modellers, it is stated the a `polar-stereographic (PS) grid` covering North America and adjacent waters with a 10 km resolution at 60 degrees north is used. How can I get the right PS for rasnc after which I will apply `projectRaster` to `rasnc` to get latlon coordinates?

Comment: This is now an entirely different question. Please edit your question (or ask a new one)